# How to hide an element when it has reached another element on scroll down?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I have a fixed button on `bottom: 0` that performs a scroll to another element, when clicked, but I need to hide it, when it reaches that element and make it appear again, when it scrolls over that element.

How could I do this with `jQuery`?

I've done this so far, but it isn't enough.

```
function hideScroller () {
    div1 = $('#form');
    div2 = $('#slide-to-contacts');

    div1FromTop = div1.offset().top;
    div2FromTop = $('body').scrollTop();

    if (div1FromTop <= div2FromTop) div2.hide();
    else div2.show();
  }
```

A rough estimate http://jsfiddle.net/ydbev5rq/5/

Comment: @AbhishekPachal added the fiddle

Comment: @Shikkediel it doesn't work. It hides the scroller long after it has passed the form, but I need it to hide the scroller only when it's over the form, on every other situation it should show.

Comment: I'll expand the answer. Thought my feedback was somewhere in between that and a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works mostly as expected I think, just an incorrect selector for div2. Best to use `$(window).scrollTop()` or if you must `$('html, body').scrollTop()` by the way.

Update - adjustment for when toggling triggers :

http://jsfiddle.net/ydbev5rq/7/

```
div2FromTop = $(window).scrollTop()+$(window).height();
```

Of course, using a `$(this)` when you can never hurts...

```
div2FromTop = $(this).scrollTop()+$(this).height();
```

Answer (score 0):

With your code it's solved.just changed div2 id and made >= to < and div1.scrollTop() to offset().top.
Here is the js code

```
function hideScroller() {
    div1 = $('#form');
    div2 = $('#scroll-to-contacts');

    div1FromTop = div1.offset().top;
    div2FromTop = $('#scroll-to-contacts').offset().top;

    if (div1FromTop < div2FromTop) div2.hide();
    else div2.show();
}
$(document).ready(function () {
    //hideScroller();
    form = $('#form');
    $('#scroll-to-contacts').click(function () {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: form.offset().top
        }, 1000);
    });
});
$(window).scroll(function () {
    hideScroller();
});
```